# Why doesn't the action method execute after return from JavaScript client side validation?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

This is probably going to be simple but I can't figure it out.  I have the following in the razor page:

```
<input type="submit" name="NewTruck" class="btn btn-primary " value="Add New Truck (Save)" onclick = "validateForm()" />
```

And the validateForm() just checks to make sure entries are correct.  All is great with the validations.  I'm getting to the end where the alert says it's done but the action method on the post is not called. Sorry to include the whole thing but I though it might be necessary.

I've also tried it with the onclientclick:

```
<input type="submit" name="NewTruck" class="btn btn-primary " value="Add New Truck (Save)" onclick = "validateForm()" onclientclick = "return validateForm()" />
```

```
function validateForm(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var truckYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('Year').value);
    if (isNaN(truckYear)) {
        alert("Truck Year must be an integer between 1925 and 2100: " + truckYear);
        return false;
    }
    if (truckYear < 1925 || truckYear > 2100) {
        alert("Truck Year must be an integer between 1925 and 2100: " + truckYear);
        return false
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('TruckNumber')) {
        var truckNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('TruckNumber').value);
        if (isNaN(truckNumber)) {
            alert("Truck Number must be an integer");
            return false
        }
        if (truckNumber < 0) {
            alert("Truck Number must be a positive integer");
            return false
        }
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('CountyDecalNumber')) {
        var countyDecalNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('CountyDecalNumber').value);
        if (isNaN(countyDecalNumber)) {
            alert("County Decal Number must be a number");
            return false
        }
        if (countyDecalNumber < 0) {
            alert("County Decal Number must be a positive number");
            return false
        }
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('NumberBagsFluidAbsorption')) {
        var numberBagsFluidAbsorption = parseInt(document.getElementById('NumberBagsFluidAbsorption').value);
        if (isNaN(numberBagsFluidAbsorption)) {
            alert("Number Of Bags Of Fluid Absorption must be a number");
            return false
        }
        if (numberBagsFluidAbsorption < 0) {
            alert("Number Of Bags Of Fluid Absorption must be a positive number");
            return false
        }
    }
    alert("end of test");
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Here is the total HTML.

```
@model Towins.Models.T_Trucks

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddTruck";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add Truck</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTruck_Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="text" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="NewWrecker" class="col-form-label">Wrecker Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="WreckerCo" name="WreckerCo" value="@ViewBag.WreckerCo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="Year" class="col-form-label">Year</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Year" name="Year" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="Make" class="col-form-label">Make</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Make" name="Make" />
        </div>            
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="Tag" class="col-form-label">Tag</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tag" name="Tag" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="VIN" class="col-form-label">VIN</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="VIN" name="VIN" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="TruckNumber" class="col-form-label">TruckNumber</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TruckNumber" name="TruckNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-1">
            <label for="WreckerClass" class="col-form-label">Wrecker Class</label>
            <select name="WreckerClass" id="WreckerClass" class="form-control">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="R">R</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="CountyDecalNumber" class="col-form-label">County Decal Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CountyDecalNumber" name="CountyDecalNumber" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="InsuranceCarrier" class="col-form-label">Insurance Carrier</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InsuranceCarrier" name="InsuranceCarrier" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="PolicyNumber" class="col-form-label">Policy Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PolicyNumber" name="PolicyNumber" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="TruckAppearance" class="col-form-label">Truck Appearance</label>
            <select name="TruckAppearance" id="TruckAppearance" class="form-control">
                <option value="Satisfactory">Excellent</option>
                <option value="Unsatisfactory">Good</option>
                <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
                <option value="Unsatisfactory">Unsatisfactory</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="AmberLightCondition" class="col-form-label">Amber Light Condition</label>
            <select name="AmberLightCondition" id="AmberLightCondition" class="form-control">
                <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
                <option value="Unsatisfactory">Unsatisfactory</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-4">
            <label for="FluidAbsorbtion" class="col-form-label">Fluid Absorbtion 50 lbs X 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="FluidAbsorbtion" name="FluidAbsorbtion" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label for="NumberBagsFluidAbsorption" class="col-form-label">Number Bags Fluid Absorption</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NumberBagsFluidAbsorption" name="NumberBagsFluidAbsorption" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="InfoOnTruck" class="col-form-label">Info On Truck</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="InfoOnTruck" name="InfoOnTruck" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="Shovel" class="col-form-label">Shovel</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Shovel" name="Shovel" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="SafetyChains" class="col-form-label">Safety Chains</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="SafetyChains" name="SafetyChains" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="CrowBar" class="col-form-label">Crow Bar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="CrowBar" name="CrowBar" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="PushBroom" class="col-form-label">Push Broom</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="PushBroom" name="PushBroom" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="Axe" class="col-form-label">Axe</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Axe" name="Axe" checked value="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="BoltCutters" class="col-form-label">Bolt Cutters</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="BoltCutters" name="BoltCutters" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="PryBar" class="col-form-label">Pry Bar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="PryBar" name="PryBar" checked value="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="TruckIsApproved" class="col-form-label">Truck is Approved</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="TruckIsApproved" name="TruckIsApproved" checked value="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="InspectedBy" class="col-form-label">Inspected By</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InspectedBy" name="InspectedBy" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="SNumber" class="col-form-label">S Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SNumber" name="SNumber" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="CarNumber" class="col-form-label">Car Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CarNumber" name="CarNumber" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="DateOfInspection" class="col-form-label">Date Of Inspection</label>
            <div id="DateOfInspection-group" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateOfInspection" name="DateOfInspection" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    @{Model.WreckerId = @ViewBag.wId;}
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WreckerId)
    <a href="@Url.Action("TruckList", new { wId = ViewBag.wId })" class="btn btn-primary">Close (No Save)</a>
    <input type="submit" name="NewTruck" class="btn btn-primary " value="Add New Truck (Save)" onclick = "validateForm()" onclientclick = "return validateForm()" />
</div>
            
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the `<form>` element, the request made to the server from the browser, and the server-side action you're expecting it to reach?

Comment: You've called `event.preventDefault()`. That will prevent the submission, no matter what.

Comment: `if (!document.getElementById('TruckNumber')) {` means that it cannot find the element with that id, and yet you use it right after that, parsing the value. You say that "All is fine with the validations"?

Comment: I had to call event.preventDefault() to keep it from submitting regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Yes.  I just double checked and it fires whether or not false is returned to the element with event.preventDefault() not in there.  I'm still confused.

Comment: if you want to your post to be send after validation you have to submit the form with javascript. put  `document.getElementsByClassName("AddTruck_Post")[0].submit();` after `alert("end of test");` in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add id to your form,and submit the form after `alert("end of test");`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTruck_Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new { id="myForm"}))
{
   ...
   <div class="modal-footer">
     @{Model.WreckerId = @ViewBag.wId;}
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WreckerId)
     <a href="@Url.Action("TruckList", new { wId = ViewBag.wId })" class="btn btn-primary">Close (No Save)</a>
     <input type="submit" name="NewTruck" class="btn btn-primary " value="Add New Truck (Save)" onclick = "validateForm()"  />
   </div>
}
```

js:

```
function validateForm(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var truckYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('Year').value);
    if (isNaN(truckYear)) {
        alert("Truck Year must be an integer between 1925 and 2100: " + truckYear);
        return false;
    }
    if (truckYear < 1925 || truckYear > 2100) {
        alert("Truck Year must be an integer between 1925 and 2100: " + truckYear);
        return false
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('TruckNumber')) {
        var truckNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('TruckNumber').value);
        if (isNaN(truckNumber)) {
            alert("Truck Number must be an integer");
            return false
        }
        if (truckNumber < 0) {
            alert("Truck Number must be a positive integer");
            return false
        }
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('CountyDecalNumber')) {
        var countyDecalNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('CountyDecalNumber').value);
        if (isNaN(countyDecalNumber)) {
            alert("County Decal Number must be a number");
            return false
        }
        if (countyDecalNumber < 0) {
            alert("County Decal Number must be a positive number");
            return false
        }
    }
    if (!document.getElementById('NumberBagsFluidAbsorption')) {
        var numberBagsFluidAbsorption = parseInt(document.getElementById('NumberBagsFluidAbsorption').value);
        if (isNaN(numberBagsFluidAbsorption)) {
            alert("Number Of Bags Of Fluid Absorption must be a number");
            return false
        }
        if (numberBagsFluidAbsorption < 0) {
            alert("Number Of Bags Of Fluid Absorption must be a positive number");
            return false
        }
    }
    alert("end of test");
    $("#myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I thought it was simple.  Just something I didn't know about js.  Thank you so much for the elegant solution and the education.